# Show that $S$ is closed in $l^\infty(X)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $l^\infty(X)$ such that the set $\{x_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is totally bounded. Show that $S$ is closed in $l^\infty(X)$.

So let $\{\tilde {x}_m\}$ where $\tilde {x}_m=(x_n^m)$ be a sequence in $S$ that converges to $\tilde {x}\in l^\infty(X)$. Then we have that $\{x_n^m: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$'s are totally bounded for each $m$. Let $\tilde {x}=(x_n)$. Want $\{x_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is totally bounded. But I have no idea how to use the fact that $\{x_n^m: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$'s are totally bounded, since it is infinite. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show $(x_n)$ is totally bounded, so fix some $\epsilon > 0$. Since $(x^m_n) \to (x_n)$ uniformly in $n$, we know there is an $M$ such that $m \geq M$ implies $\|x^m_n - x_n\| < \epsilon/2$ for all $n$. Since $(x^M_n)$ is totally bounded, there exist a finite set $F \subset X$ such that, for each $n$, we have $\|x^M_n - y\| < \epsilon/2$ for some $y \in F$. But then, $\|x_n - y\| < \epsilon$ by the triangle inequality, so $(x_n)$ is also totally bounded.